# Can you identify those parts (sensors), on test aircraft and the purpose?

Tags: flight-instruments, flight-testing

I have seen many photos with those sensors attached to the test aircraft, Can you provide why they are used and what do they measure?

[image]

Here is another example on SuperJet:

[image]

Comment: The "rope" helps reduce the static on test aircrafts so the testing sensors and instruments work more precise. The "spike" is a long pitot tube, which measures the pressure way before the airplanes body starts changing it (you can see this for high speed planes too, where the mass of air they push in front of them would have a significant impact on a pressure measured close to the aircrafts body). A quick Google search can help a lot to get more information.

Answer (score 2):

On the super jet that's a pitot tube rather large but still it's a testing aircraft. Aircraft's use pitot tubes to measure airspeed. The example, from an Airbus A380, combines a pitot tube (right) with a static port and an angle-of-attack vane (left). Air-flow is right to left. A pitot (/ˈpiːtoʊ/ PEE-toh) tube is a pressure measurement instrument used to measure fluid flow velocity. And so on, The basic pitot tube consists of a tube pointing directly into the fluid flow. As this tube contains fluid, a pressure can be measured; the moving fluid is brought to rest (stagnates) as there is no outlet to allow flow to continue. This pressure is the stagnation pressure of the fluid, also known as the total pressure or (particularly in aviation) the pitot pressure. Go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitot_tube), for evidence.

Comment: Question is why it's so special on the test aircraft? Do they compare readings with standard tubes on the side of fuselage to know corrections for the position error? Otherwise long tubing can introduce errors like delays ect.

Comment: Yes, They do compare The "long" pitot tubes to the normal length'd one, Why is it so special to test on aircraft? Well (No offence) You should know that people are always trying to make bigger, better aircraft " Do they compare readings with standard tubes on the side of fuselage to know corrections for the position error?" Yes they do Quite often, Hope that's answered your Question.